# Sikuli - text not shown correct in IDE

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide, sikuli-x

I am usin Sikuli for the first Time. I downloaded Sikuli ide 2.0.4, and jython into the same folder.
after running sikuli IDE and writing a text (e.g. click()) the text is shown wrong:
[image_Text_wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/471pF.png)

Did anyone else already had this issue as well? How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the ones who have the same problem:

you can change the fonts in "Preferences" and "text Editing". Somehow it choosed a wrong font by default in my case.